# Detecting if a DOM object can be placed in a SPAN

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wrapping sections of an arbitrary web page ("from character X to character Y") in SPANs with the following constraints:

1. I do not want to break any DOM standards (for instance I don't want to wrap a DIV in a SPAN).
2. I want to minimize the number of SPANs created (so it isn't enough to just go to the lowest child level possible).

I need to know if a given object can legally be contained in a SPAN before I modify the DOM.

**For Instance...**

```
if(child instanceof Text) {
 // Wrap in a SPAN!
}
else {
 // Move along
}
```

In particular I need the list of JavaScript classes that reflect valid SPAN-able content, a method (jQuery or vanilla JS) that might be able to help, or another solution that would accomplish a similar goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `span` only permits [*phrasing-content*](http://developers.whatwg.org/content-models.html#phrasing-content). I would suggest building a small table of all elements that make up the *phrasing-content* collection and test against this.

This isn't a perfect solution, since some intra-paragraph elements, like the `a` tag can also contain non-phrasing content. You may need to recursively evaluate the contents of elements, insuring they don't contain anything but phrasing-content within themselvse, before you permit them to be wrapped in a `span` tag.